# Resource for complex pronunciation queries

Tags: pronunciation, resources

I haven't seen any questions about resources so I'm not sure if it's accepted but let's try anyway.

I recently learned that the word *quay* is pronounced /ˈkiː/. I was wondering if there are other words where *ay* makes a /iː/ sound, not necessarily at the end of the word.

Is there a website or tool where I can find such an information? Somewhere I can input parts of a word and phonetics, and see what words match both? Or anything else that would answer that type of question.

I figured I could use a rhyme dictionary but it wouldn't cover occurrences where the bigram is not at the end of the word.

Comment: Another word where "ay" is pronounced /i/ is *cay*